# Search substring in a object of a array of objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, axios

I have a array of objects. In object, I have string value in each object. I have to search specific substring in the string.

```
[
    {
        "link": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1702510/000170251022000084/0001702510-22-000084-index.htm",
        "summary": "\n <b>Filed:</b> 2022-12-23 <b>AccNo:</b> 0001702510-22-000084 <b>Size:</b> 25 KB\n<br>**Item 3.02**: Unregistered Sales of Equity Securities\n<br>Item 7.01: Regulation FD Disclosure\n"
    },
    {
        "link": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1853774/000182912622020524/0001829126-22-020524-index.htm",
        "summary": "\n <b>Filed:</b> 2022-12-23 <b>AccNo:</b> 0001829126-22-020524 <b>Size:</b> 940 KB\n<br>**Item 1.01**: Entry into a Material Definitive Agreement\n<br>Item 9.01: Financial Statements and Exhibits\n"
    },
    {
        "link": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1859007/000149315222036510/0001493152-22-036510-index.htm",
        "summary": "\n <b>Filed:</b> 2022-12-23 <b>AccNo:</b> 0001493152-22-036510 <b>Size:</b> 278 KB\n<br>**Item 1.01**: Entry into a Material Definitive Agreement\n<br>Item 9.01: Financial Statements and Exhibits\n"
    },
....
]
```

I have search substring like "Item 3.02" in summary value. if the substring found get object and return array of object that contains substring value

I have tried tried match and includes methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to traverse the array and string search in the object. Here's the same code:

```js
const data = [
    {
        "link": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1702510/000170251022000084/0001702510-22-000084-index.htm",
        "summary": "\n <b>Filed:</b> 2022-12-23 <b>AccNo:</b> 0001702510-22-000084 <b>Size:</b> 25 KB\n<br>**Item 3.02**: Unregistered Sales of Equity Securities\n<br>Item 7.01: Regulation FD Disclosure\n"
    },
    {
        "link": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1853774/000182912622020524/0001829126-22-020524-index.htm",
        "summary": "\n <b>Filed:</b> 2022-12-23 <b>AccNo:</b> 0001829126-22-020524 <b>Size:</b> 940 KB\n<br>**Item 1.01**: Entry into a Material Definitive Agreement\n<br>Item 9.01: Financial Statements and Exhibits\n"
    },
    {
        "link": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1859007/000149315222036510/0001493152-22-036510-index.htm",
        "summary": "\n <b>Filed:</b> 2022-12-23 <b>AccNo:</b> 0001493152-22-036510 <b>Size:</b> 278 KB\n<br>**Item 1.01**: Entry into a Material Definitive Agreement\n<br>Item 9.01: Financial Statements and Exhibits\n"
    }
]

const textToSearch = "Item 7.01";

const filteredItems = data.filter((item) => {
  return item.summary.includes(textToSearch);
});

console.log(filteredItems);
```

Comment: than you so much. Is there any fastest way to search to search?.

Comment: @AliHassan For faster searching methods, you can explore string search algorithms like Rabin–Karp algorithm. From my understanding, "includes()" is the fastest method provided by JS out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over all the items in the array and then use the `includes` string method to search for the substring.

```js
const data = [
  {
      "link": "...",
      "summary": "\n <b>Filed:</b> 2022-12-23 <b>AccNo:</b> 0001702510-22-000084 <b>Size:</b> 25 KB\n<br>**Item 3.02**: Unregistered Sales of Equity Securities\n<br>Item 7.01: Regulation FD Disclosure\n"
  },
  {
      "link": "...",
      "summary": "..."
  },
]

function findItems(searchString) {
  return data.filter((item) => item.summary.includes(searchString));
}

const items = findItems("Item 3.02")
console.log(items);
```